# Communication from Python to Arduino over USB

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am trying to communicate with an Arduino. I use python and pyserial for communication over USB. As you can see in the source code below, I am trying to send a bytearray, which contains some information for two ledstrips, to the Arduino. But the Arduino does not receive the right information. It looks like the bytearray is transformed or information is getting lost.

I searched the whole day for a solution, but nothing has worked. Hopefully one of you can help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

**Python Code**

```
import sys
import serial
import time

HEADER_BYTE_1 = 0xBA
HEADER_BYTE_2 = 0xBE


def main():
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 57600)
    message = { 'header': [None]*2, 'colors': [None]*6, 'checksum': 0x00 }
    message['header'][0] = HEADER_BYTE_1
    message['header'][1] = HEADER_BYTE_2
    # first led
    message['colors'][0] = 0xFF
    message['colors'][1] = 0xFF
    message['colors'][2] = 0xFF

    # second led
    message['colors'][3] = 0x00
    message['colors'][4] = 0x00
    message['colors'][5] = 0x00

    # create checksum
    for color in message['colors']:
        for bit in bytes(color):
            message['checksum'] ^= bit

    # write message to arduino
    cmd = convert_message_to_protocol(message)
    ser.write(cmd)
    print(cmd)

    time.sleep(5)
    # read response from arduino
    while True:
        response = ser.readline()
        print(response)


def convert_message_to_protocol(message):
    cmd = bytearray()
    for header in message['header']:
        cmd.append(header)

    for color in message['colors']:
        cmd.append(color)

    cmd.append(message['checksum'])

    return cmd

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Arduino Code**

```
const int kChannel1FirstPin = 3;
const int kChannel1SecondPin = 5;
const int kChannel1ThirdPin = 6;

const int kChannel2FirstPin = 9;
const int kChannel2SecondPin = 10;
const int kChannel2ThirdPin = 11;

// Protocol details (two header bytes, 6 value bytes, checksum)

const int kProtocolHeaderFirstByte = 0xBA;
const int kProtocolHeaderSecondByte = 0xBE;

const int kProtocolHeaderLength = 2;
const int kProtocolBodyLength = 6;
const int kProtocolChecksumLength = 1;

// Buffers and state

bool appearToHaveValidMessage;
byte receivedMessage[6];

void setup() {
  // set pins 2 through 13 as outputs:
  pinMode(kChannel1FirstPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(kChannel1SecondPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(kChannel1ThirdPin, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(kChannel2FirstPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(kChannel2SecondPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(kChannel2ThirdPin, OUTPUT);

  analogWrite(kChannel1FirstPin, 255);
  analogWrite(kChannel1SecondPin, 255);
  analogWrite(kChannel1ThirdPin, 255);

  analogWrite(kChannel2FirstPin, 255);
  analogWrite(kChannel2SecondPin, 255);
  analogWrite(kChannel2ThirdPin, 255);

  appearToHaveValidMessage = false;

  // initialize the serial communication:
  Serial.begin(57600);
}


void loop () {

  int availableBytes = Serial.available();

  Serial.println(availableBytes);

  if (!appearToHaveValidMessage) {
    // If we haven't found a header yet, look for one.
    if (availableBytes >= kProtocolHeaderLength) {
      Serial.println("right size");
      // Read then peek in case we're only one byte away from the header.
      byte firstByte = Serial.read();
      byte secondByte = Serial.peek();

      if (firstByte == kProtocolHeaderFirstByte &&
          secondByte == kProtocolHeaderSecondByte) {

          Serial.println("Right Header");
          // We have a valid header. We might have a valid message!
          appearToHaveValidMessage = true;

          // Read the second header byte out of the buffer and refresh the buffer count.
          Serial.read();
          availableBytes = Serial.available();
      }
    }
  }

  if (availableBytes >= (kProtocolBodyLength + kProtocolChecksumLength) && appearToHaveValidMessage) {

    // Read in the body, calculating the checksum as we go.
    byte calculatedChecksum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < kProtocolBodyLength; i++) {
      receivedMessage[i] = Serial.read();
      calculatedChecksum ^= receivedMessage[i];
    }

    byte receivedChecksum = Serial.read();

    if (receivedChecksum == calculatedChecksum) {
      // Hooray! Push the values to the output pins.

      analogWrite(kChannel1FirstPin, receivedMessage[0]);
      analogWrite(kChannel1SecondPin, receivedMessage[1]);
      analogWrite(kChannel1ThirdPin, receivedMessage[2]);

      analogWrite(kChannel2FirstPin, receivedMessage[3]);
      analogWrite(kChannel2SecondPin, receivedMessage[4]);
      analogWrite(kChannel2ThirdPin, receivedMessage[5]);


      Serial.print("OK");
      Serial.write(byte(10));

    } else {

      Serial.print("FAIL");
      Serial.write(byte(10));
    }

    appearToHaveValidMessage = false;
  }
}
```

**Example**

Generated Bytes in Python: `b'\xba\xbe\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

Received Bytes on the Arduino: `b'L\xc30\r\n'`

Answer (score 0):

Changing the baudrate to 9600 has fixed the communication